# Check if scrolled below element or to bottom of page

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a function that changes the navigation based on whether the page is scrolled to specific elements. However, the last part of this function doesn't fire on larger screens, as the page can't scroll far enough. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#contact-me').offset().top){
        $("a.current").removeClass("current");
        $("a#cont-link").addClass("current");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        alert("We are at bottom of the document!");
    }
    function ScrollHandler() {
        console.log("Scrolling...!");
    }
    $(window)
        .on('scroll', ScrollHandler);
});

$(
    function($) {
        $('#checkBotom').bind('scroll', function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                alert('We are at div Bottom');
            }
        })
    }
);
```

```css
#checkBotom{width:200px;height:150px;overflow:auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkBotom">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br>
Consectetuer augue nibh lacus at <br>
Pretium Donec felis dolor penatibus <br>
Phasellus consequat Vivamus dui lacinia <br>
Ornare nonummy laoreet lacus Donec <br>
Ut ut libero Curabitur id <br>
Dui pretium hendrerit sapien Pellentesque <br>
</div>
<div style="height: 1000px">Scroll down!</div>
```

> Note:- 
>   You can bind your function with window scroll function & detect if element scrolled or not...
>
> & You cab calculate the scrollTop() + window height & if document height same than you are at bottom of the page....